# When (if ever) is it appropriate to file a grievance about the behaviour of one the MDs in a family business?

Tags: united-kingdom, morale

I work in a start-up family business and have for a few years. The sister of the lead\head MD (an MD herself) works part time at the business. However, she constantly makes demoralizing comments including (but not limited to) that we have the minimum level of benefits allowed by law, 'joke' to female members of staff they will be replaced if they go on maternity leave (and the tactics they'd use to make them leave), and make comments that "If I were you (employees), there's no way I'd work here".

We all work incredibly hard, for little money, due to the potential present in the business. This issue has been brought to the attention of the main MD before, but nothing has happened. I have removed a lot of specifics here for the sake of anonymity, but this has gone on for a long time, and I don't think myself and my colleagues are being too sensitive or soft.

So, at what point is it advisable to [file an actual grievance](https://www.gov.uk/solve-workplace-dispute/formal-procedures) in a family business, rather than having (another) informal chat about it? And are there any tips regarding complaining about the MD in question?

Comment: What does MD stand for? Don't assume that everyone reading this question is familiar with your abbreviations.

Comment: @Chad The UK (Cardiff is in Wales) does indeed have some sort of legally defined term, but it just seems to be a fancy name for a formal complaint. See [this page on Formal Procedures at gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/solve-workplace-dispute/formal-procedures).

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with that link and tagged it UK. This should clear up some confusion... though inevitably we will get 3 or 4 answers as though this is in the US anyway.

Comment: Weird business that has more than one Managing Director, but hey. Let me ask you this: do you think the person in charge is going to favour you over their sister? If the answer to that is "yes, I reasonably believe that that is possible" then by all means go ahead...

Comment: Is MD "managing director" as some have assumed, or "medical doctor" (the common meaning of the acronym?)

Comment: "due to the potential present in the business" - but do you have equity? If not then the potential, even if eventually realized, would not benefit you.

Comment: In the UK 'Managing Director' is the common meaning of MD. 'Medical Doctor' is a North American thing.

Comment: You have a family business with multiple MD and even a part time MD and you have already brought this to the attention of the head MD but nothing happened.  You really think fling a grievance is likely to go good for you?

Answer (score 8):

In all seriousness, that would be after your CV has been updated, sent out, and been accepted by another employer.

Once you file a grievance, your life will never be the same at that company.  There will be new policies implemented which will make things more professional but more harsh at the company and they will blame you for them.  While there will be no "official" retribution, you will not be happy there.  If it's that bad, move on, but if you want to continue to work there, NO TIME is a good time to file a grievance, especially in a family business, as it will be taken VERY personally.

Comment: It sounds like the sister is only coming some of the times. Unsure what interval of time he means, but I would take that into consideration as well on top of what Richard said. If it is once a month then maybe it's not as big of a deal.

Answer (score 8):

Talk to the lead, and ask him to ask his sister to tone down the snarky comment since you have the impression that theyre hurting morale generally and they're certainly annoying you.

However, also remember that some folks just have a cynical sense of humor and she might be shocked that anyone was taking her seriously.

Formal grievance is the nuclear option. Try a brokered peace first.

Comment: I don't see another answer that doesn't involve playing "you bet your job", preemptively leaving, or learning to ignore the cynic.

Answer (score 4):

> So, at what point is it advisable to file an actual grievance in a
>   family business, rather than having (another) informal chat about it?

In general, you should take formal actions when

- Sufficient informal actions have taken place
- The informal actions haven't resulted in an acceptable outcome
- You are willing to bear the consequences associated with the formal action (costs, time, persistence, social impact, possible informal retaliation from coworkers and employer, etc)
- The issue at hand is serious enough
- Your own record is extremely clean

Don't ever treat the filing of a formal action casually. Once you start things in motion, they are exceedingly hard to stop, and can have difficult consequences even if you succeed.